# What is Stateism in the context of Ronald Reagan calling it a "naked desert?

Tags: terminology, political-science

The short National Review Institute video [William F. Buckley Jr. Legacy Video](https://youtu.be/x-xPUdLBOUg?t=158) plays an audio recording of [Ronald Reagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Reagan) presumably addressing [William F. Buckley Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_F._Buckley_Jr.) with Reagan saying:

> You didn’t just part the Red Sea, you rolled it back, dried it up, and left exposed for all the world to see, the naked desert that is Stateism.
>
> And you did it without an environmental impact statement.

Wikipedia's [Stateism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statism) begins:

> In political science, statism or etatism is the doctrine that the political authority of the state is legitimate to some degree. This may include economic and social policy, especially in regard to taxation and the means of production.

*In moderation*, not all of that sound terribly evil in his view; certainly Reagan was solidly for the collection of at least some taxes to pay for a few [pet projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Reagan#Escalation_of_the_Cold_War).

**Question:** How would choosing to serve as the president of a country be consistent with believing that seeing the government as having some political authority was a "naked desert"? Did Reagan then feel that the political authority of the US government *was not legitimate?* Am I confusing terminology here somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Oxford languages definition may be more useful to understand the rhetoric:

> a political system in which the state has substantial centralized control over social and economic affairs.

And this is what Reagan and the conservative movement (of which Buckley, Reagan and others were a part) were specifically opposed to. Statism, in this sense, is the policy of "big government", and Reagan uses it as an attack term. So we can modify our understanding of Reagans meaning to "a system in which the state has *unjustifiably* centralized control and *coercion* over social and economic affairs, *to the detriment of individual liberty*."

Reagan would not have seen himself as a "statist" in that sense. He believed in small government, but not the absence of government.  He believed in lowering taxes, not eliminating them.

A rhetorical understanding of the term is necessary because Reagan is speaking in heightened terms.  Reagan is not giving a scientific analysis, but a panegyric.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is a somewhat off-brand use of the term statism. 'Statism' is normally used from the international relations perspective, as a claim about the rights of a state to rule within established borders. Most political scientists would have the term 'federalism' in this context. I'm not certain if this was Reagan flubbing the concept, or if there was some particular reason he wanted to tweak the term in a new direction. But in any case, I've never heard anyone else use it that way, so...

Comment: @TedWrigley Isn't federalism a system where the national government delegates most powers to individual states? I think statism here is being used to refer to the national government.

Comment: @Barmar: No, it's the reverse: where power becomes more centralized in the federal government. as opposed to a confederation, where more power is delegated to individual states.

Comment: @Barmar Some of that is doing to depend who is making the distinction and what they're comparing. You could also have federalist versus unitary, which would be in the direction you've indicated. There is no universal book of definitions, along with regional and language differences which make this confusing. Just look at the issues in distinguishing between a country, a nation and a state.